# jquery validation ie8 submitHandler not firing

Tags: jquery-validate

I have this script:

```
var pUserName = $('#UserName'), pPassword = $('#Password'), pRememberMe = $('#RememberMe');

$(function () {
    Initialize();

    $('#logon button').click(function () {
        $.event.trigger('AjaxButtonClick', this);
        $.event.trigger('AjaxLoader', '#logon .form');
        $('form#logon').valid();
    });
});

function Initialize() {
    returnUrl = getParameterByName('ReturnUrl');

    $('form#logon').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            logOn(returnUrl);
        },
        invalidHandler: function (e, validator) {
            showAnimatedStatusText($('.message'), 'Please fill in the required fields highlighted below.', 'warning');
            $.event.trigger('AjaxButtonError');
            $.event.trigger('AjaxLoader');
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            return true;
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().addClass("input-validation-error");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass("input-validation-error");
        }
    });
};

function logOn(returnUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/_Account/LogOn',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{ "UserName": "' + pUserName.val() + '", "Password": "' + pPassword.val() + '", "RememberMe": ' + pRememberMe.is(':checked') + ', "returnUrl": "' + returnUrl + '" }',
        dataType: 'text json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (o) {
            if (o.success) {
                // Success code

                $.event.trigger('AjaxButtonSuccess');
            } else {
                showAnimatedStatusText($('.message'), o.error, 'error');
                $.event.trigger('AjaxButtonError');
            }

            $.event.trigger('AjaxLoader');
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            showAnimatedStatusText($('.message'), 'An uncaught error has occurred, please contact your system administrator (Error code: 150).', 'error');
            $.event.trigger('AjaxButtonError');
            $.event.trigger('AjaxLoader');
        }
    });
};
```

this works fine in all browsers except ie8. For some reason the submitHandler is never called. If I enter incorrect data invalidHandler is called fine, but submitHandler never is.

Does anyone know why?

Cheers,
/r3plica

Comment: I have found if I change my <button>Sign in</button> to <input type="submit" value="Sign in" /> it works. Is there anyway to get this to work with a <button> rather than an input?

Comment: This is why you should include the HTML in your question.

Comment: Did you try `<button type="submit">SignIn</button>`?

Comment: yeah I did but it had the same effect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that using a  element in ie8 does not appear to work the same way as an  even if you supply . To get this working I had to change my validation script to look like this:

```
    $('#logon').validate({
        submitHandler: function () {
            // Do not submit
        },
        invalidHandler: function (e, validator) {
            showAnimatedStatusText($('.message'), 'Please fill in the required fields highlighted below.', 'warning');
            $.event.trigger('AjaxButtonError');
            $.event.trigger('AjaxLoader');
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            return true;
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().addClass("input-validation-error");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass("input-validation-error");
        }
    });
```

and the calling button click look like this:

```
    $('#logon button').click(function () {
        $.event.trigger('AjaxButtonClick', this);
        $.event.trigger('AjaxLoader', '#logon .form');
        if ($('#logon').valid()) {
            logOn(returnUrl);
        };
    });
```

doing it this way fixed the issue.